# Создание таблицы с помощью printf

Tags: c++

```
printf("| Метод | Размер массива | Количество сравнений | Количество обменов | Скорость |\n");
printf("|Метод прямого выбора | %d | %d | %d | %.10f |\n", n, cmp, assigns, seconds.count());
printf("|Метод прямого включения|        %d        |           %d            |          %d         |         %.10f         |\n", n, cmp, assigns, seconds.count());
printf("|Метод прямого обмена | %d | %d | %d | %.10f |\n", n, cmp, assigns, seconds.count());
printf("|Быстрая сортировка | %d | %d | %d | %.10f |\n", n, cmp, assigns, seconds.count());
```

У меня есть алгоритмы сортировок с их характеристиками.Значения везде разные,поэтому у меня все сдвигается вправо.
Пытался сделать что-то подобное,но все колонки кроме 1 не робят:
printf("|%-23s|%d-18s|%d-24s|%d-22s||%.10f-30s|\n","Метод простого обмена", n, cmp, assigns, seconds.count());
Как-то можно так сделать,чтобы у меня были фиксированные колонки и не сдвигались при увеличении чисел? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]Скриншот приложил.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1396571/2739

Comment: `%d` -> `%10d`.